# What have been the arguments against VAT in the US?

Tags: united-states, economy, taxes

The majority of countries in the world have implemented a [Value Added Tax (VAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_tax) - sometimes called a Goods and Services Tax (GST) - why hasn't the US?

EDIT - I would assume that if a VAT were implemented it would replace sales tax and the like at least to some degree, not asking why we don't have another tax stacked on top of our current ones
[image: VAT]

Comment: Perhaps it would be more practical to ask about arguments for such a tax.  AFAIK there have been no real arguments against, because it's never been seriously considered.  One argument, and perhaps the best, would be the problems involved in replacing one tax mechanism with another.

Comment: One could ask why other countries don't have sales taxes.

Comment: One reason why other countries have VAT taxes is that they're generally waived/rebated for exports, making the country's products cheaper in international trade.  And, contrary to statements that VAT is a "sales tax", it's actually closer to a corporate/business income tax, as it is collected from each business in the chain and is based on the company's gross profits.

Comment: @jamesqf I've personally heard/read conservatives rail against it rather harshly a number of times. The most common argument I've heard is that [it's too easy to raise because it's less visible](https://www.wsj.com/articles/should-the-u-s-adopt-a-value-added-tax-1456715703).

Comment: @HotLicks: Its based on "value added", not on gross profit. So if you just pass on something at cost, your VAT contribution is 0.

Comment: @BradHards if you pass goods on at cost, your gross profit will also be zero (which is why people don't do that).  Gross profit is the difference between revenue and cost of goods sold, which is also how added value is calculated.

Comment: We also might re-word the question another way: why don't those VAT countries adopt a US-like system, given that the US economy seems more successful than most?  Which could be asked about a good number of other things :-)

Comment: @jamesqf - Is the US economy more successful?   How do you measure "success" -- the number of billionaires, the number of people living in poverty, the number without adequate healthcare?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Per capita GDP: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2004rank.html Leave out the micro-states making money as tax havens &c, and the ones whose wealth comes almost entirely from oil, and the US is pretty close to the top.

Comment: If you compare implementations in western europe against the political arguments answered below, it seems clear to be a personal issue for politicians rather than not wanting upgrading one’s country tax system

Comment: @jamesqf it could be quite possible that the measure of what success is might be wrong here. A US-system is bad for most people, which is what many countries value higher than money or economic bottom line. You might have higher highs, but there a whole lot more lower lows as well, and to many non-US countries, that is unacceptable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Liberal/bipartisan arguments against a VAT](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/040715/what-are-some-arguments-and-against-value-added-tax-vat.asp):

1. Most states already have sales taxes and value added taxes (VATs) are essentially a tax on sales.
2. VATs are regressive, as they tax consumption rather than income and the poor consume a larger portion of their income.
3. While businesses pay VAT to the government, they collect the money from their customers.  Liberals prefer taxes that they can claim come from businesses and their owners to ones on employees and customers.

[Conservative/libertarian arguments against a VAT](https://www.cato.org/publications/congressional-testimony/case-against-valueadded-tax):

1. A VAT reduces the value of savings, as part of the savings will be used to pay the VAT.
2. A border-adjusted VAT is essentially a tax on imports, like a tariff.
3. Countries with VATs tend to add them to existing taxes rather than replacing existing taxes with VATs.  This leads to more taxes and spending.

United States specific reasons:

1. Sales taxes are state taxes but a state could not charge a border-adjusted VAT due to constitutional limitations (states can't tax imports from other states).  It would have to be a federal tax.
2. The non-border-adjusted version taxes exports from one state to another.  Most states do not want to do that, as it puts their goods at a competitive disadvantage with other states.
3. Since sales taxes are state taxes and VAT is a federal tax, it would be complicated to reduce the (state) sales tax while imposing a federal VAT.
4. Adding a federal law to raise taxes for a state is politically difficult.  The politician gets the blame for the tax increase but doesn't get the credit for the spending.  Politicians prefer the reverse, where they get the credit and someone else takes the blame.  Or at least want to get the credit as well as the blame.
5. Donald Trump thinks that it is [too complicated](https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-01-18/trump-is-right-border-adjustment-tax-is-complicated).

Comment: Isn't your first "conservative/libertarian" argument against VAT actually an argument against tax in general?  Furthermore, it assumes that reduction in value of savings is bad, which is hardly axiomatic; whether reducing savings is good or bad depends on whether the savings rate is too high or too low.  Also, "states can't tax imports from other states" is either untrue or irrelevant: states routinely charge sales tax on goods produced elsewhere.  Look at Canada for an example of state (provincial) and federal taxes coexisting.

Comment: "VATs are regressive, as they tax consumption rather than income and the poor consume a larger portion of their income." - VAT/GST can be targeted and have services lower income people depend on be exempt (transit, food, shelter) and generally gets applied to luxuries more than necessities.  Though this ups the complexity a little though, but I generally do not hear VAT/GST as regressive because it can be exempted on products low income use more.

Comment: @phoog  Please take it up with the Cato institute, as shown by the citation.  And states can't charge sales tax on products produced elsewhere unless the seller has a local nexus.  The problem with VAT is that the default is to tax on export; changing that to import is unconstitutional.

Comment: @Brythan the place of production is completely irrelevant to sales tax, only whether the seller has a "local nexus" as you note.  A Pennsylvania retailer who has no presence in New York will not charge sales tax on apples shipped to NY whether the apples were grown in NY or elsewhere in the US or in another country.

Comment: Excise taxes (federal/state/city level) on things like cigarettes show that it's hardly unconstitutional to charge varying taxes in different states for the same product, since it's viewed as an event tax (the act of buying) rather than an import or tariff . Oddly enough, they also seem to rebut almost every point on both the liberal and conservative lists above. Point 4 in the US-specific list is the most relevant here I think. And I guess 5 is relevant too, but I don't even want to get into that.

Comment: in Canada we called it the "Gouge and Screw Tax". It was unpopular in provinces without a sales tax because it was a new tax that went to Ottawa and Quebec, but didn't do anything locally.  It was unpopular in provinces with sales taxes because provincial sales taxes were not decreased.

Comment: Ironically, in the US there is a small group of people, primarily conservatives, who promote replacing all federal taxes with a single sales tax. However, this would immediately disrupt the entire sector of the economy that is driven by complexity of current tax regulations and virtually eliminate the leverage of the federal government to use tax incentives for political purposes.

Comment: @Brythan The Cato's institute's argument is exactly what phoo says: That holds for any tax. They just want to refute the argument that the VAT is less anti-savings than other taxes. (As they state in the article you conveniently linked.)

Comment: @Twelfth which itself causes paradoxes and is arguably very moralistic approach - like why razor is essential when women's hygiene products are not (I think this is real life sales tax example). Or why should eating caviar (food) be subsidized by changing oil (service). Probably better approach would be a regressive VAT per person - skipping aside for a moment logistic of such project and privacy intrusion.

Comment: You might also add to the conservative/libertarian viewpoint something about it being "too easy to raise." You can find an example of this opinion [here](https://www.wsj.com/articles/should-the-u-s-adopt-a-value-added-tax-1456715703) (the David R. Henderson opinion).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka But making system that's 100% accurate would make it impractically complex. But still, for poor people that spend significant part of their income on food (reduced VAT rate) their effective VAT rate is lesser than for richer people spending money on goods and services with nominal VAT rate. Maybe with exception of crazy millionaires who buy nothing but caviar.

Comment: I find the "regressive" and "collect from customers" arguments a bit weak insofar as factually in places where you do have VAT, it's the _conservatives_ who lower VAT and the liberals/socialists who raise them beyond reason. France during the last 5 years being the most compelling recent example where the reduced VAT rate doubled under Hollande, among them agricultural products, transports, and repair cost.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka - Female hygiene products should also be exempted, simply because some other nation decided to tax them doesn't mean other implementations should.  Using caviar is a silly example as it's not exactly a low income food, perhaps my wording would have been better as 'essential' foods.  Bread, eggs, milk, and a large variety of foods can see the exemption while others not considered 'essential' are not.  It can get weird though, The issue came up of 1 donut = taxed.  4 pack of donuts = not taxed because a 4 pack is a family oriented sale.

Comment: @Twelfth That was a point 'caviar' was supposed to be example of definitely non-low-income food. Once you try to cut up on the 'luxuries' and 'non-luxuries' you start make a judgment of very broad categories and lifestyles which does not necessary matches up with reality and you might end up penalizing some groups unintentionally. In this aspect the regressive consumption tax/sales tax is better as it does not make claims if, say, organic eggs are luxury while caged are not. Or, for that matter, income tax.

Comment: @el.pescado I think it's a bit too overbroad simplification to divide consumption to the only low-income and high-income. Spending pattern of different subgroups of those categories might vastly differ. In cities having a car is a luxury due to good public transport while outside it might be necessity. It can be also argue that staying in one place instead of moving to lower-cost area is luxury... or that it is necessity. This issue is orthogonal to division of people into low-income and high-income people.

Comment: "VATs are regressive, as they tax consumption rather than income" -> ...and regular sales taxes are not regressive? Where's the logic in that?

Comment: @JonathanReez  Most people who are against VATs for being regressive are also against sales taxes, preferring income or property taxes instead.

Comment: @Brythan yes, but its disingenuous to claim that replacing salex taxes with VAT is wrong because that would be a regressive tax

Comment: @JonathanReez  That comment in the question was added after I posted this.  I still maintain that it is one of the reasons why people oppose VATs.  It is also, as I explained, disingenuous to argue that a VAT would replace the sales tax at all.  Because sales taxes are state and local while VATs are national.  VATs have generally been proposed in the US either as an additional tax or a replacement for personal or corporate income tax.

Answer (score 4):

One argument omitted from otherwise excellent answer by Brythan is that it - or rather, border adjustment tax that will probably accompany it - will possibly gut the retailers (especially cheap Wal-Mart type importers).

This is covered in a great detail (with specific math on how border adjustment effects work) in Vox's article "[House Republicans are proposing a big corporate tax cut that Walmart hates](https://www.vox.com/2016/12/25/14069822/corporate-tax-border-adjustability)":

> That’s why retailers are revolting against the idea of border adjustment. As David French, the head lobbyist at the National Retail Federation, told Politico, “**Our members have told us that the import tax could be as high as five times their profits. I don't know how viable some retailers would be in the face of this import tax**."
>
> Barney Jopson of the Financial Times reported, “Senior lobbyists who sometimes struggle to get the attention of company leaders told the Financial Times they were receiving calls from chief executives with orders to fight the tax plan, which some importers say threatens to wipe out their profits.” Walmart, Best Buy, Target, and Walgreens have all been meeting with Ways and Means Chair Brady’s office about the issue, according to Bloomberg BNA reporters Aaron Lorenzo and Kaustuv Basu.

Obviously, mostly this argument is made by importer retail industry - but it can be argued that it would have at least immediate negative impact on (frequently low income) consumers who depend on Wal-Marts of the country to buy cheap foreign-produced stuff.